# phpunit impossible to follow the installation process

Tags: php, ubuntu, phpunit

I have a lot of problems trying to intall phpunit, maybe my knowledge isn't enought or the guide is very incomplete.

First, the install, I tried all the ways, globally, with "downloaded PHAR file directly" or with "`sudo apt-get install phpunit`" but when I tried to do:

```
$phpunit -v
bash: /usr/bin/phpunit: No chuch file or directory
```

if I do:

```
$ ll /usr/local/bin (I know, the path is different, other unexplicable event)
-rwxr-xr-x 1 user user 2784899 abr 29 17:09 phpunit*
```

but

```
$ sudo phpunit --version
PHPUnit 7.1.5 by Sebastian Bergmann adn contributors.
```

ok, looks better, so I tried to make the first example

```
<?php
use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

class StackTest extends TestCase
{
    public function testPushAndPop()
    {
        $stack = [];
        $this->assertSame(0, count($stack));

        array_push($stack, 'foo');
        $this->assertSame('foo', $stack[count($stack)-1]);
        $this->assertSame(1, count($stack));

        $this->assertSame('foo', array_pop($stack));
        $this->assertSame(0, count($stack));
    }
}
```

but it give me the next error:

```
PHP Fatal error: Class 'PHPUnit\Framework\Testcase' not found in /var/www/html/phpunit/index.php on line 4
```

I'm using Ubuntu 18 and php 7.2

Any idea?

Comment: Which guide are you referring to? Any feedback on the [official guide](https://phpunit.de/getting-started-with-phpunit.html) is very much appreciated.

Comment: When it worked you used sudo, when it didn't you didn't. It's not just as simple as permissions?

Comment: but the user is my current user, and I don't have problems to see other software version.
And Yes, I follow the official guide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I start to understand some things.
First @Sebastian Bergmann give me the clue, with [this](https://phpunit.de/getting-started/phpunit-7.html) example, it works.

But if you start with the [documentation](https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/7.1/) you never found it. I think it's an error and can confuse a begginer like me.

Yet I can't install phpunit with PHAR or globally, maybe it could be a future new post.

Thanks for all

Comment: A beginner should start with the [website](https://phpunit.de/], which prominently points to the "getting started" guide, and not with the documentation.

Comment: You also want to avoid a "global installation", be it using Composer, PHAR, or RPM/DEB, as that only leads to problems when you have different requirements between several projects.

Answer (score 0):

When you are running PHPUnit from the command line, you also need to include a 'bootstrap' file - it can be as simple as the composer autoload.php file:

```
phpunit --bootstrap vendor/autoload.php
```

Longer term, that configuration would be put into the phpunit.xml file so it is read, and run automatically by PHPunit.

```
<!-- file: phpunit.xml
     src/autoload.php would also include the ./vendor/autoload.php file
     and do any other locally required setup -->
<phpunit bootstrap="src/autoload.php">
  <testsuites>
    <testsuite name="money">
      <directory>tests</directory>
    </testsuite>
  </testsuites>
</phpunit>
```

Comment: I find a lot of files named phpunit.xml, and if I look for the text:
`grep -re '<phpunit bootstrap' .` It's in ./vendor/phpunit/phpunit/tests/_files/configuration_empty.xml

Comment: You need to make your own, and put it in the base directory. The website has examples of adding test-suite(s) (your own test class to run), and other potential configurations.  Details are in the documentation.